# ExpandableListView not showing child views

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, radio-group, expandablelistadapter

```
public class ItemOptionsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<String> categoryList;

public ItemOptionsListAdapter(Context context, List<String> categoryList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

private TextView title(View v, int resId, String text){
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);
    tv.setText(text);
    return tv;
}

private ImageView image(View v, int resId, int icon){
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
    return iv;
}

class ItemListViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView dropdownArrowImage;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return categoryList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return categoryList.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return "size";
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ItemListViewHolder categoryItemViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null) { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_row_layout, null); 
        categoryItemViewHolder = new ItemListViewHolder(); 
        convertView.setTag(categoryItemViewHolder); 
    } 
    else { 
        categoryItemViewHolder = (ItemListViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }
    categoryItemViewHolder.title = title(convertView, R.id.category_name_text, categoryList.get(groupPosition));
    categoryItemViewHolder.dropdownArrowImage = image(convertView, R.id.dropdown_arrow_image, 0);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) { 
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_list_layout, null);
    } 
    Log.d("child", " in getChildView()");
    TextView itemPropertyTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_option_property);
    itemPropertyTextView.setText((String)"Size");
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

My child views are going to be static and each group is meant to contain a single child
childlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_option_property"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Size" />

    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/item_option_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <RadioButton android:text="Small"/>
       <RadioButton android:text="Medium"/>
       <RadioButton android:text="Large"/>

   </RadioGroup> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Group View layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#50ffffff" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/category_name_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/dropdown_arrow_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:rotation="270" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also from logs, I know that the `getChildView` never gets called

Thanks in advance

edit: I just noticed one thing, as soon as the groupView appears, a small scroll to its right flashes which gives an indication the all is working fine but the view itself isnt completely visible. But still dont seem to fix it.

My expandable list xml:

```
<ExpandableListView 
   android:id="@+id/item_option_list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:groupIndicator="@null" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: you hardcoded getChildrenCount as 1.

Comment: yes because each of the groups is gonna contain one single static child view

Comment: in your getChild you are returning string "size" and also in your textview you have the same "size" so it will be always "size". R U not  getting any single child view?

Comment: Am not getting any child, infact the `getChildView()` isnt getting called at all

Comment: Make sure that you don't have focusable views in the group view and that you return false from the on group click listener if you set any.

Comment: I added group layout as well

Comment: I have also tried adding `android:focusable="false"` in both `ImageView` and `TextView` in group layout. Doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you've clicked the group header, 'cause the children are collapsed by default.

Also, to be sure not having a problem of focusability, try to expand programmatically.

`expandableListView.expandGroup(0);`

Comment: I know, I did check that, as I mentioned, I know from the logs the `getChildView()` never gets called

Comment: I remember Android uses kind of a lazy way, the `getChildView()` method is not called until you expand the group. You may do a for loop and expand all your groups after you've set up the adapter for the ExpandableListView to have a try.

Comment: What difference could expanding programmatically make over expanding manually by a tap?

Comment: No difference. Just in case your group click event not triggered. By the way, you have any log in OnGroupClickListener and OnGroupExpandListener?

Comment: @trojantale Searching for hours and just find that the group wasn't clickable. Discover this by programmatically expand a group. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in the top layout of the group:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 1):

On going over the posted code, everything seems right. I would suggest trying the following to find out the issue.

1) In the layout inflate part add the following.

In getGroupView function :

`convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list_row_layout, parent, false);`

In getChildView function :

`convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_option_list_layout, parent, false);`

The above lines of code will make sure it picks up the proper layout properties from its parent ViewGroup.

2) Add the log message Log.d("child", " in getChildView()"); in the beginning of the function which will let give us a clue as whether the function have not been called or there are any exception in rendering the view from the given layout.

3) Try constructing and returning a simple TextView from the getChildView() and then add complex views in incremental fashion.

Comment: Here are the results
I do step 1, no change
I do step 2, no change and still nothing in logs
I do step 3, no change and still nothing in logs

Comment: Oh ! That's really strange. Can you paste the code snippet as how you are using the expandable list view and feeding the adapter to the list. (onCreate/ onStart/ onResume of the activity)

Comment: I could find the xml but not the activity code using the xml and adapter.

Comment: Also , you can try returning simple textview alone from the getGroupView() method  to check whether any  problem with focusability as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888574/expandablelistview-child-click-listener-not-firing

Comment: The list is working fine I checked it by setting the layout around my expanableListView to 200 dp. But why isnt the wrapContent working for expandableListView.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and I found my issue.
The ExpandableListView's layout_height attribute was `wrap_content` which defaults to just the header. So you have 2 options to fix this.

Option 1 : Fix the layout_height to some value.

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

Option 2 : Programattically change the listview's height in onCreateView and wherever appropriate.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = expandableListView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = array_list.size() * 20;
expandableListView.setLayoutParams(params);
expandableListView.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with another Group View layout. I also met this problem and I deleted some(I think not need) `android:` in the highest LinearLayout and It works. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is coming rather late, however for other readers...

The issue is caused by your

`groupview linearlayout` having **horizontal** orientation.

`android:orientation="horizontal"` -> set this to `vertical` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Button or ImageButton with default properties will not work. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015230/android-expandablelistview-parent-with-button) for more details.