# Not getting a childPosition/groupPosition when clicking on child or checkbox in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to make ExpandableListView where every child has a checkbox and every group has TextView where later I want to output text with amount of selected children out of total (i.e. 3/26, for example). For now I'm just trying to get the groupPosition and childPosition of the clicked child or the checkbox in the child view. But when I click on them - nothing happens, I don't get no log record, not Toast message.

Here's my code from Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ChildHolder child_holder;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_base_item_selected, null);
        child_holder = new ChildHolder();
        child_holder.tv_bi_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_base_item_name_selected);
        child_holder.chb_selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chb_selected);
        convertView.setTag(child_holder);
    } else {
        child_holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Group group = arr_groups.get(groupPosition);
    final Base_Item base_item = group.getGroup_items().get(childPosition);

    if(base_item!=null)
    {
        child_holder.tv_bi_name.setText(base_item.getItem_name());
        if(base_item.isBase_item_selected())
        {
            child_holder.chb_selected.setSelected(true);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Group group = arr_groups.get(groupPosition);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_group, parent, false);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_name)).setText(group.getGroup_name());
    ImageView img_add = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_add_category);
    img_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onImageClicked(group.getGroup_id());
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

class GroupHolder{
    TextView tv_group_name;
    TextView tv_items_counter;
}

class ChildHolder{
    TextView tv_bi_name;
    CheckBox chb_selected;
}
```

This is the Activity code:

```
Task_DB_Manager manager;
ArrayList<Group> arr_all_groups;
Add_Edit_Trip_Expandable_ListView_Adapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit_trip_relative);

    lv_trip_list     = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv_trip_list);

    manager = new Task_DB_Manager(this);

    populate_list();
}

private void populate_list()
{
    arr_all_groups = manager.get_all_groups();

    adapter = new Add_Edit_Trip_Expandable_ListView_Adapter(this, arr_all_groups);
    lv_trip_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv_trip_list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Log.e("Group position :: "+groupPosition, " &&   Child position :: "+childPosition);
            Toast.makeText(Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.this, "Group position :: "+groupPosition+"\nChild position :: "+childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    set_image_click_listener();
}
```

Why don't I get the childPosition and groupPosition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888574/expandablelistview-child-click-listener-not-firing):

apparently I had to set this for the checkbox in the XML:

```
android:focusable="false"
```